# Systemd Service Script Not Echoing

Tags: fedora, scripting, systemd

I've recently setup Fedora 22 onto a machine and it's using the systemd init system.

I've been reading up on it and now I need to create a systemd start up script for postgresql

For testing I created the following shell script, hello_world

```
#! /bin/sh
#  testing systemctl script

start() {
   echo "Executing Start"
   echo "Testing 01"
   echo "Testing 02"
   echo "Testing 03"
}

stop() {
   echo "Stopping Hello World Script"
}

case "$1" in
   start)
      start
   ;;
   stop)
      stop
   ;;
   restart)
      stop
      sleep 2
      start
   ;; 
   *) exit 1
esac
```

Which when I run it using the terminal it does what I expect and echos the strings

```
. hello_world start
```

This echos "Starting Hello World Script" then I placed it inside /usr/lib/systemd/scripts

Then I tried to create the systemd service script as follows, hello_world.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Hello World Testing Script

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/hello_world start
ExecStop=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/hello_world stop
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Which I placed inside /usr/lib/systemd/system and tried to execute with

```
systemctl start hello_world.service
```

Which did not give any errors but I did not get the echo string that I expected when i executed the hello_world script alone.

So I can't tell if it is actually working, did I miss something? why is the systemctl command not echoing the string from the script?

Comment: systemd is not a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system.  I'm surprised the postgresql package doesn't include systemd scripts.

Comment: It does echo your messages but not where you expect it as the log target is journal. If you run `journalctl -f` in a terminal and then start your service in another terminal you will see in the first terminal: `systemd[1]: Starting Hello World Testing Script... hello_world[5038]: Starting Hello World Script systemd[1]: Started Hello World Testing Script.` where `hello_world[5038]: Starting Hello World Script` is your actual script echoing the message.

Comment: @lior, postgresql does include start-scripts however they are system v scripts so they cannot be ran by systemctl without a systemd script to handle it. I'm talking about installing from source. Installing with dnf will include a systemd script but I need to install from source

Comment: @don, thanks for the info don, is there a way to echo the message to the terminal when using systemctl because it's a bit of a pain to keep checking log files

Comment: If you want to see output in console (VT) add `StandardOutput=tty` to your `[Service]` section. If you just want to play with it in the current terminal then run `tty` (should return something like `/dev/pts/2`) and add a second line `TTYPath=/dev/pts/2` under `StandardOutput=tty`; after editing the service file run `systemctl daemon-reload` and then starting/stopping your service should echo to current terminal...

Comment: I'd extract the systemd scripts from the dnf package and modify them.  Look up rpm2cpio.

Comment: It seems excessive to reinstall postgres with dnf to get the systemd file, if anyone knows of a way for the systemd script to output to the terminal then that's all I really need considering the postgresl system v script works fine I just can't see what it's doing without two terminal sessions

Comment: You don't need to install the postgresql with dnf.  Just do `wget https://mirror.umd.edu/fedora/linux/releases/22/Server/x86_64/os/Packages/p/postgresql-server-9.4.1-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm` and then `rpm2cpio postgresql-server-9.4.1-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm | cpio -i --to-stdout "*postgresql.service" > postgresql.service`

Comment: @Trent It seems you found the answer, but edited it into the question. You should write a brief answer, accept it, and take the answer snippet out of your question.

Comment: Ok Centimane I will do this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the output for the script is not sent to the terminal it is instead redirected to the status command

After the service is running

```
# systemctl start hello_world.service
```

I can view my outputs in the status

```
# systemctl status hello_world.service
```

Which will include any outputs from the script like bellow

```
Apr 28 10:18:00 centos7.adminserv systemd[1]: Starting Hello World Testing S....
Apr 28 10:18:00 centos7.adminserv hello_world[18164]: Executing Start
Apr 28 10:18:00 centos7.adminserv hello_world[18164]: Testing 01
Apr 28 10:18:00 centos7.adminserv hello_world[18164]: Testing 02
Apr 28 10:18:00 centos7.adminserv hello_world[18164]: Testing 03
Apr 28 10:18:00 centos7.adminserv systemd[1]: Started Hello World Testing Sc....
```

Comment: That is just showing you relevant lines from journal. It's the same thing if you did `journalctl -f` just filtered specifically for that unit file, which you can also do using journalctl command if you wanted.